# Convert custom class object to IEnuerable for its use in foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a custom class student as below:

```
     public class Student
     {
         public string Name {get;set;}
         public string GuardianName {get;set;}
     }
```

Now, I have data coming in the following data structure

```
      IList<Student> studInfo=new List<Student>();
```

I have put this data in the viewbag

```
      Viewbag.db=studInfo;
```

On the view page, when I try to use

```
    <table>
       <thead>
            <tr>
                 <td>Name</td>
                 <td>Guardian Name</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

     @foreach(var stud in ViewBag.db)
     {
          <tr>
              <td>@stud.Name</td>
              <td>@stud.GuardianName</td>
          </tr>

     }
    </table>
```

There is an error, saying

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'PuneUniversity.StudInfo.Student' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
```

PuneUniversity is my namespace and StudInfo is the Application name. Please suggest me a solution.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: That *looks* like you're doing the right thing already, other than the issue Darin pointed out. Are you sure the code you've given is exactly what you've got in your failing solution?

Comment: Why dont you try List<Student> studInfo = new List<Student>();

Comment: Ah...the other thing is that ViewBag.db is dynamic (i think...), therefore, it may not know in your foreach loop that ViewBag.db is of type List<Student> because it is being read as dynamic, therefore, you could try performing an explicit cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is unlikely to compile:

```
IList<Student> studInfo = new IList<Student>();
```

You cannot create instances of interfaces. So I guess that your actual code is different from what you have shown here.

Also I would recommend you using strongly typed views instead of ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    IList<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    students.Add(new Student { Name = "foo", GuardianName = "bar" });
    return View(students);
}
```

and now make your view strongly typed:

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Guardian Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(var stud in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@stud.Name</td>
            <td>@stud.GuardianName</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks ...can u suggest me a way to put the class properties in the table. That is, instead of writing the <thead> data manually, I want it to be rendered from class property names.